# Efficient way to compare elements in 2 lists

Tags: python

I want to compare entries in 2 lists:

for example:

```
for key in keys:
        for elem in elements:
            #Find a key in common with 2 lists and write the corresponding value
            if key == elem:
                 do something
            #Iterate through elements unit the current "key" value is found.
            else:
                 pass
```

Problem with this method is that it is very slow, is there a faster way to do this?

*Assuming `len(keys) > len(elements)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use sets, and then set intersection will return the common elements.

Set intersection is an `O(min(len(s1), len(s2))` operation.

```
>>> s1 = range(10)
>>> s2 = range(5,20)
>>> set(s1) & set(s2)  #set intersection returns the common keys
set([8, 9, 5, 6, 7])   # order not preserved
```

Answer (score 1):

Turn them into sets:

```
set1 = set(keys)
set2 = set(elements)
```

And now you can find their intersection:

```
set1.intersection(set2)
```

The sets won't preserve order, so you'll get back just the common elements.

Comment: just to note that `set.intersection` can accept an iterable so the conversion of elements to `set2` is strictly not needed.