# Efficient way to compare elements in two lists?

Tags: python

I know this is similar to [Efficient way to compare elements in 2 lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16974839/efficient-way-to-compare-elements-in-2-lists), but I have an extension on the question basically.

Say I have two lists:

```
a = [1,2,4,1,0,3,2]
b = [0,1,2,3,4]
```

I want to find out the indices of `a` where the element is equal to each element of `b`.

For instance, I would want the sample output for `b[1]` to tell me that `a = b[1]` at `[0,3]`.

A data frame output would be useful as well, something like:

```
   b  index_a
   0     4
   1     0
   1     3
   2     1
   2     6
   3     5
   4     3
```

What I used before was:

```
b = pd.DataFrame(b)
a = pd.DataFrame(a)
pd.merge(b.reset_index(),a.reset_index(),
         left_on=b.columns.tolist(),
         right_on = a.columns.tolist(),
         suffixes = ('_b','_a'))['index_b','index_a']]
```

However, I am unsure if this is necessary since these are for lists. ( I used this method previously when I was working with dataframes ).

I am doing this operation thousands of times with much larger lists so I am wondering if there is a more efficient method.

In addition, b is just `list(range(X))` where in this case `X = 5`

If anyone has some input I'd greatly appreciate it!

Thanks

Comment: Can we assume that all elements of `a` will be contained in `b`?

Comment: Well, `b` is useless. the real information is just `N`. You can just create a mapping from values in the range `0..N-1` to indices of `a`. And to build this mapping you simply have to loop over `a`. Note that element with value `x` in `b` is at index `x` (because `b = list(range(N))`). In fact given that the mapping has consecutive integers as keys a list-of-lists is sufficient: `indices = [[] for _ in b]; for i,x in enumerate(a):indices[x].append(i)`

Comment: Yes, sorry I should've mentioned that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import collections
dd=collections.defaultdict(list)
for i,x in enumerate(a):
    dd[x].append(i)

>>> sorted(dd.items())
[(0, [4]), (1, [0, 3]), (2, [1, 6]), (3, [5]), (4, [2])]
```

Answer (score 2):

A very simple and efficient solution is to build a mapping from the values in the range `0..N-1` to indices of `a`. The mapping can be a simple list, so you end up with:

```
indices = [[] for _ in b]
for i, x in enumerate(a):
    indices[x].append(i)
```

---

Example run:

```
>>> a = [1,2,4,1,0,3,2]
>>> b = [0,1,2,3,4]
>>> indices = [[] for _ in b]
>>> for i,x in enumerate(a):
...     indices[x].append(i)
... 
>>> indices[1]
[0, 3]
```

Note that `b[i] == i` so keeping the `b` list is pretty useless.

Comment: Ah ok I see. I had a feeling `b` might be useless but I wasn't sure how to do it otherwise. Do you mind providing an example if I were to get rid of `b`?

Comment: @GarrettMiller if you don't know the size of b ahead of time, my answer is perfect. If you do, you can initialize `indices = [[] for _ in range(length)]` and this answer works best.

Comment: @GarrettMiller Change `for _ in b` with `for _ in range(N)` or `for _ in [0]*N`

Comment: @MarkRansom The OP explicitly said that the size of `b` is known in advance. In any case you can always use `[[] for _ in range(max(a))]`. I find that using a `dict` where the keys are consecutive integers is a bit of a waste.

Answer (score 1):

If b is sorted consecutive integers as you shown here, then bucket sort is most effective.
Otherwise, you may construct a hash table, with value b as the key, and construction a list of a's as values.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is efficient enough for your needs, but this would work:

```
from collections import defaultdict

indexes = defaultdict(set)

a = [1,2,4,1,0,3,2]
b = [0,1,2,3,4]

for i, x in enumerate(a):
    indexes[x].add(i)

for x in b:
    print b, indexes.get(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
def listChecker(listA: list, listB: list) -> list:
"""
Checks for elements in `listA` that are not present in `listB`.

This function efficiently iterates through `listA` and adds elements not found in
`listB` to the `out_list`. It leverages set operations for both membership testing
and list creation, potentially enhancing performance in certain scenarios.

Args:
    listA (list): The first list to compare against.
    listB (list): The second list to check for common elements.

Returns:
    list: A new list containing elements from `listA` that are not present in `listB`.

Raises:
    TypeError: If either `listA` or `listB` is not of type `list`.

Examples:
    >>> listChecker([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 3, 5])
    [2, 4]
    >>> listChecker([], [1, 2, 3])
    []
    >>> listChecker(["apple", "banana", "cherry"], ["apple", "orange"])
    ["banana", "cherry"]
"""

if not isinstance(listA, list):
    raise TypeError("listA must be a list")
if not isinstance(listB, list):
    raise TypeError("listB must be a list")

# Convert lists to sets for efficient membership testing and list creation
setA = set(listA)
setB = set(listB)

# Use set difference to efficiently find elements not in listB
missing_elements = setA.difference(setB)

return list(missing_elements)  # Convert the set back to a list
```

Have fun \m/